# Windows batch to loop through the files in the folder and parse the file name

Tags: windows, loops, parsing, batch-file

How do I loop through the files in the folder and parse the portion of the file name and store it in a variable + echo?

Folder contains following files and need to pull out the year:

```
Actual2015.txt
Actual2016.txt
```

What I tried:

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
set year=%%f:~7,4%
echo %year%
)
```

result should be:

> 2014
>
> 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set fname=%%nf
  set year=!fname:~6,4!
  echo !year!
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Just made the minor adjustment

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set fname=%%f
  set year=!fname:~6,4!
  echo !year!
)

Comment: @User1786 - fixed.

Comment: Missing the tilde.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can take the last 4 characters of the file name if you know that last 4 are what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set fname=%%~nf
  set year=!fname:~-4!
  echo !year!
)
pause
```